# Search with Django Haystack: no search results

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I try to run the haystack, but i have not any data back. Search works but without result

I start:

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> sqs.count()
```

I recieve the following mistake: Failed to query Solr using '*:*': [Reason: None]
I can't find where is the mistake.
Thanks Andrey

Comment: Add some information about what you have in search_indexes.py , url.py , search.html, data_template

Comment: The mistake looks like: 'code' "Failed to query Solr using '(\*)': [Reason: None]
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":6,"params":{"facet":"on","fl":"* score","start":"0","q":"(\\*)","facet.field":["type_exact","location_exact"],"wt":"json","fq":"django_ct:(jobs.job)","rows":"0"}},"error":{"msg":"undefined field django_ct","code":400}}
[20/Jun/2013 19:14:04] "GET /?q=* HTTP/1.1" 200 2453" 'code'           All fiels  i copied from [link] https://github.com/broderboy/django-solr-demo [link] and nothing changed.